# Calculating RSS manually with given pairs of beta0 and beta1

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to manually calculate the RSS for a dataset with given pairs of beta0 and beta1. For each (beta_0,beta_1) pair of values, I need to calculate the residual sum of squares. Store it as a vector in `data` called `RSS`. Here's the code provided.

```
x = pinotnoir$Aroma
y = pinotnoir$Quality
fit = lm(y ~ x)
summary(fit)
b0s <- seq(0, 10, .1)
b1s <- seq(0, 4, .01)

data <- expand.grid(beta0=b0s, beta1=b1s)
```

Here's what I have so far. I think the residual calculation is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
rows = length(b1s)
rsd <- rep(NA,rows)
for (i in 1:rows){
  residual = (y - (b0s[i] + b1s[i] * x))^2
  rsd[i] <- residual
}
data <- expand.grid(beta0=b0s, beta1=b1s, RSS=rsd)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! I'm thinking this question might get a better result if it were posted on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is exactly what you aim but adapting your code slightly you can get the sum of squared residuals and which betas minimizes them. (using mtcars data for the example)

```r
mtcars
x = mtcars$drat
y = mtcars$wt
(fit = lm(y ~ x))
summary(fit)
grid_len <- 20
b0s <- seq(5, 10, length.out = grid_len)
b1s <- seq(-3, -1, length.out = grid_len)

(data <- expand.grid(beta0=b0s, beta1=b1s))

rows = nrow(data)
resids <- rep(NA,rows)
for (i in 1:rows) {
  fitted <- (data$beta0[i] + (data$beta1[i] * x))
  squared_resid  <- (y - fitted)^2
  SSR <- sum(squared_resid)
  resids[i] <- SSR
  cat(i, ": ", SSR, "\n")
}

data[which.min(resids), ]
fit
```

results:

```
> data[which.min(resids), ]
       beta0     beta1
332 7.894737 -1.315789
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      7.906       -1.304
```